# Are there any interpreted languages which use keywords like int, float and string to declare a variable?

Tags: interpreter, language-design

I am writing an interpreter. The language I am creating uses keywords like `int`, `string` and `float` to declare variables, e.g.:

```
int x = 20

string y = "hello"
```

However in Python or PHP these keywords are not needed, e.g.:

```
$x = 20

$y = "hello"
```

or

```
x = 20

y = "hello"
```

Is it a good idea to add data-type keywords support in interpreted languages?

Are there any languages (interpreted) which use such keywords?

Comment: The problem is not not use _keywords_ but to have a typed language. You can interpret C or C++ etc, these language do not _force_ to compile them (even their definition allow to compile them producing efficient code), long time ago in [xcoral](http://xcoral.free.fr/) I made an interpreter managing a subset of C to allow to extend the editor without having to compile. But what it your _real_ question, what do you need ?

Comment: You don't need those keywords in C++ either, you could just say `auto x = 20; auto y = "hello";`. But it is a very good idea to have an explicit declaration syntax. It doesn't have to be types; e.g. JavaScript uses `let x = 20;` or Perl uses `my $y = "hello";`.

Comment: Basic. Java. Pascal, in its p-code versions. The list is endless.

Comment: There is no such a thing as an "interpreted" language. C++ interpreters exist, as well as optimising Python compilers. Of course, you can design a language with interpretation or static compilation in mind, but it should be the least important consideration when you design a language (unless performance is particularly important). And static vs. dynamic typing is a dimension totally orthogonal to compiled vs. interpreted.